# oracle adf how to space between 2 columns?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-adf

I have oracle adf and jdeveloper.
I have a table in jsf page.
I want to put space between 2 columns and insert 2 button in that space.
can anyone help me to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an extra "Column" component to the table then add the button.